# Error : The BIOS In This System Is Not Fully ACPI Compliant

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, bios, asus-laptop

I have an ASUS x541UJ laptop and when i'm trying to install Windows 7(I tried multiple Windows, still the same error) i get a blue screen with writing "The BIOS In This System Is Not Fully ACPI Compliant". I tried updating the BIOS with the latest version, but still gives me that error. What can I do ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1310245/the-bios-in-this-system-is-not-fully-acpi-compliant

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The BIOS in this system is not fully ACPI compliant](https://superuser.com/questions/1310245/the-bios-in-this-system-is-not-fully-acpi-compliant)

Comment: No. I don't have options like "OS Version" or switching to Legacy or UEFI.